# How to check input string with no spaces & special characters except two special charaters (that is & and Ñ)

Tags: regex, jquery-plugins

I am trying to validate an `input string` (which can be copied & pasted in the textbox).
The input entered should contain one or more `alphabetic characters`, numbers and two more special characters as (`&` and `Ñ`), but no embedded spaces.

NB: Alphabetic characters must present, but numbers & those two special characters may or may not present to create a valid input.

I am using Jquery for client side validation.

- **Alternative Approach:**

  If anyone can help me how we can detect the occurrence of any special characters and spaces, except '&' and 'Ñ' in any input string, then also my problem can be resolved.

Comment: I'm confused upon reading your question again: In the title you say you want to validate if the string contains special characters *except* `&` and `Ñ`; in the question text it sounds like those two are the only allowed special characters - which is it?

Comment: I am using Java script & Jquery to validate in client side inputs.

Comment: Yes, those two characters & and Ñ are only alloweed special characters in my input string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I am done with the validation with `Jquery alphanumeric` plugin

i.e `"$('#txtId').alphanumeric({ allow: "&Ñ" });".`

Explanation: This allows all `alpha numeric` characters & restricts all other characters (special characters got addressed). In the allow part I could place the allowable special characters.

Answer (score 1):

Detecting what is not allowed in this situation would not be a good idea. You mentioned that detecting special characters other than those two (Ñ, &) and space would be acceptable. What about tabs? What about new line characters? What about non-latin characters? If you are confident that this would never happen then go ahead with the detection of special characters. If a match is made in the following regex then the input is not valid:

> [\~!\@#\$\%\^\&*()_+\=-[]{}\\|\'\"\;\:\/\?.>\,\<`]

The solution that is provided above is good that it checks that the correct characters were used however it will match even if any of the special characters above are used. I guess this is not what you want. Here is a modified version:

> ^(([A-Za-z]+[^A-Za-z\d&Ñ]*)|([^A-Za-z\d&Ñ]*[A-Za-z]+)|([^A-Za-z\d&Ñ]*[A-Za-z]+[^A-Za-z\d&Ñ]*))$

If this matched then the input is valid otherwise it's not. This is probably not the most efficient regex but it should work.

Btw, some sample input text would really help!

---

Version without capital letters:

> ^(([A-Z]+[^A-Z\d&Ñ]*)|([^A-Z\d&Ñ]*[A-Z]+)|([^A-Z\d&Ñ]*[A-Z]+[^A-Z\d&Ñ]*))$

Comment: Thanks Uphill. I am done with other scenarios, just need one last thing. My input string only allows alphanumeric (caps A to Z & 0 to 9) & two special characters i.e. '&' and 'Ñ'. Also there should not be any spaces in between.

Comment: Even better! The regex should be: ^(([A-Z]+[^A-Z\d&Ñ])|([^A-Z\d&Ñ][A-Z]+)|([^A-Z\d&Ñ][A-Z]+[^A-Z\d&Ñ]))$

Comment: ^[A-Z0-9&Ñ]+$ is the correct reg exp that I am looking for: Regex to check only capital alphabates, two special characters (those are & and Ñ) & without any space between. Anyways thanks for the patience to discuss the pros & cons

Comment: Actually it's not correct based on your description unless I didn't understand it clearly. If you require at least one alphabetic character then my regex is the correct one. If you require at least one character but it can be anything including numbers and the 2 special characters then yours is the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to allow capital letters, digits, and `&` or `Ñ` as valid characters, then use

```
^(?=.*[A-Z])[A-Z\d&Ñ]*$
```

Verbose regex:

```
^                   # anchor the search at the start of the string
(?=.*[A-Z])         # assert that there is at least one letter A-Z in the string
[A-Z\d&Ñ]*       # match any number of allowed characters
$                   # anchor the search at the end of the string
```

You might want to impose a minimum length, though, as currently the string `A` would be a valid input. For example, `^(?=.*[A-Z])[A-Z\d&Ñ]{8,}$` would ensure a minimum length of 8.

If you want a regex that will match if the input contains a non-allowed character, then you can use

```
[^A-Z\d&Ñ]
```

But then you need a second regex to also ensure that there is at least one letter in your input. I'd argue the first approach is more readable, even in JavaScript where you can't use verbose/commented regexes.

Comment: Thanks Tim, But this looks bit complicated. Is it possible for you to help me with Alternative approach that I ve stated above?    that is:            "how can we detect the occurance of any special characters and spaces, except '&' and 'Ñ' in any input string".

Comment: No more complicated than your rules :)

Comment: Alternative Approach: "how can we detect the occurance of any special characters and spaces, except '&' and 'Ñ' in any input string".

Comment: How is this less complicated and also ensures that there is at least one letter?

Comment: Actually I am done with all validation with one regex exp & a Jquery alphanumeric plugin i.e "$('#txtId').alphanumeric({ allow: " &Ñ" });". Now I am able to restrict the characters, but the user can still copy paste any character set.            So I am planning to validate the entered text again, just to check if any special characters (other than '&' and 'Ñ') or space is pasted by the user. Hope this will clarify the scenario now.

Comment: I don't quite see the point of that. What happens if your user cuts (Ctrl-X) a section of the input so that the only letter he entered is gone? As I understand it, you'll have to do a complete validation of the final string. But I don't know JQuery. Anyway, I have edited my answer and added a "illegal character detection regex".

Comment: ^[A-Z0-9&Ñ]+$ is the correct reg exp that I am looking for: Regex to check only capital alphabates, two special characters (those are & and Ñ) & without any space between. Anyways thanks for the patience to discuss the pros & cons.

Comment: OK, I have again edited my answer. You too should edit your question and specify that you only want to allow capital letters, otherwise my answer doesn't fit the question as it is currently stated.