# Regex to check only capital letters, two special characters (& and Ñ) & without any space between

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I am using below code snippet to validate my input string with: only capital letters, numbers and two special characters (those are & and Ñ) & without any space between.

```
var validpattern = new RegExp('[^A-Z0-9\d&Ñ]');
if (enteredID.match(validpattern))
   isvalidChars = true;
else
   isvalidChars = false;
```

Test 1: `"XAXX0101%&&$#"` should fail i.e `isvalidChars = false;` (as it contains invalid characters like `%$#`.

Test 2: `"XAXX0101&Ñ3Ñ&"` should pass.

Test 3: `"XA 87B"` should fail as it contains space in between

The above code is not working, Can any one help me rectifying the above regex.

Comment: What about your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976420)?

Comment: Maybe you should remove the negation ^.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is happening because you have a negation(`^`) *inside* the character class.

What you want is:  `^[A-Z0-9&Ñ]+$` or `^[A-Z\d&Ñ]+$`

Changes made:

- `[0-9]` is same as `\d`. So use
  either of them, not both, although it's not incorrect to use both, it's redundant.
- Added start anchor (`^`) and end
  anchor(`$`) to match the *entire*
  string not *part* of it.
- Added a quantifier `+`, as the
  character class matches a *single*
  character.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but let me know which part of the regex is responsible for checking the spaces?

Comment: @Biki: We are **allowing only** upper case letters, digits and the two special char. So this automatically does not allow any **other** characters like the space.

Comment: Ya, Very true. Using jquery we could achieve the same in one line: $('#txtFederalTaxId').alphanumeric({ allow: " &Ñ" });

Answer (score 3):

```
^[A-Z\d&Ñ]+$
```

`0-9` not required.

Answer (score 1):

if you want valid patterns, then you should remove the `^` in the character range.

`[A-Z0-9\d&Ñ]`

Answer (score -1):

Using jquery we could achieve the same in one line:

```
$('#txtId').alphanumeric({ allow: " &Ñ" });
```

Using regex (as pointed by codaddict)  we can achieve the same by

```
var validpattern = new RegExp('^[A-Z0-9&Ñ]+$');
```

Thanks everyone for the precious response added.

Comment: This "in one line" thing isn't a useful metric of "good code". Often a higher count of shorter lines gives your readers better understanding of your intent (and more scope to refactor later). However... if you want a "pure JS" one-liner, try something based on: `isvalidChars = /^[A-Z0-9&Ñ]+$/.test(enteredID)`. This works because JS supports RegEx literals.